# Is it mandatory to convert the object in string before sending it to server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, web-applications

```
var json_data = {"attribute_1":"some_value_1","attribute_2":"some_value_2"};
$.ajax({
  url: "some_url",
  type: "POST",
  async: false,
  data: json_data,
  cache: false,
  success: function(response) {}
});
```

Is it mandatory to convert the object in string like `JSON.stringify(json_data)` before sending it to server side ? What about this ?

**Update after further research :-**

If i don't data is passed as string as `attribute_1=some_value_1&attribute_2=some_value_2` but if call Stringify data is still passed as string but as `attribute_1:some_value_1,attribute_2:some_value_2`. First string is not correct json format while second is correct. So I am not sure why jquery internal stringify does not convert data in correct json string ?

Comment: No. You can send Object also.

Comment: You can send it as an object. That just means jQuery will convert it for you.

Comment: why are you using `async:false`? This is well known to produce a horrible user experience by locking up the browser and making it un-usable during the request, and is also down to be removed as a feature from the XHR spec. There is almost never a reason to need it.

Comment: Before sending to the server: Yes, but jquery does it for you, so you can pass an object to jquery.

Comment: Please see mine edit about the difference i observed

Comment: is attribute_2 in JS actually an object itself, or just a string. It kind of looks like it might be a string. If it was an object, it should have been properly serialised by jquery. So either make that a proper object on the client side, or manually decode it from JSON on the server-side

Comment: @ADyson yes attribute_2 is an json object itself but it still it is passed as in form of associative array element in request parameter ?

Comment: ok according to http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/ (which is what is used internally to do this serialisation, it cannot cope with complex objects such as that, and you should set the content type as JSON instead and the server should expect to deserialise JSON

Comment: @ADyson Please see mine Edit 2 after adding contentType and removing Stringify

Comment: " is passed two times as separate parameter instead of single string ". No it isn't. The two parameters are Attribute2[note] and Attribute2[userId]. It's just that the square brackets got URL-encoded.

Comment: So in first case it is passed as single string with attribute name as Attribute2 while in second case its passed as separate parameters. Right ? I believe back end code like jackson objectmapper will change to handle both approaches ?

Comment: @ADyson Can you please see mine last comment ?

Comment: I don't know anything about jackson objectmapper specifically, but I see no reason, in theory, why that structure couldn't be parsed by the server. If you can't make it work, like I said earlier you might be better sending the whole lot as JSON

Comment: All, please see mine update